# Convert from string to int in c# Using Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#

I have a simple code in c# that converts a string into int

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(aTestRecord.aMecProp);
```

`aTestRecord.aMecProp` is of `string`. The test I am running, during that it has values of `1.15` in `string`.

but above line throws error saying that input string wasn't in a format!

I don't understand why?

I am using VS 2008 c#

Comment: Maybe convert to double first and then to int can't test it at the moment

Comment: Well what is an integer? It's a *whole number*. Have you had a look at C#'s data types?

Comment: The string value 1.15 is actually not a whole number. It is float value.

Comment: That is because it is a float value that you are trying to convert

Comment: Do you want rounding? lets say: 1.5 => 2?

Answer (score 1):

An integer can only represent strings without a decimal part.
1.15 contains a decimal part of 0.15.
You have to convert it into a float to keep the decimal part and correctly parse it:

```
float f = Convert.ToSingle(aTestRecord.aMecProp);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `1.xx` is not a integer valid value. You could truncate before converting to `Int32`, for sample:

```
int result = (int)(Math.Truncate(double.Parse(aTestRecord.aMecProp)* value) / 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to validate that a string is an integer, use TryParse()

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse(aTestRecord.aMecProp, out i))
{

}
```

`i` will get assigned if TryParse() is successful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double i = Convert.ToDouble(aTestRecord.aMecProp);
```

Or if you want the integer part:

```
int i = (int) Convert.Double(aTestRecord.aMecProp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to double and then typecast it

```
string str = "1.15";
int val = (int)Convert.ToDouble(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
Int32 result =0;
Int32.TryParse(aTestRecord.aMecProp, out result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a C# equivalent for the JavaScript parseInt function? I have used this one on occasion:

```
public int? ParseInt(string value)
{
    // Match any digits at the beginning of the string with an optional
    // character for the sign value.
    var match = Regex.Match(value, @"^-?\d+");

    if(match.Success)
        return Convert.ToInt32(match.Value);
    else
        return null; // Because C# does not have NaN
}

...

var int1 = ParseInt("1.15"); // returns 1
var int2 = ParseInt("123abc456"); // returns 123
var int3 = ParseInt("abc"); // returns null
var int4 = ParseInt("123"); // returns 123
var int5 = ParseInt("-1.15"); // returns -1
var int6 = ParseInt("abc123"); // returns null
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I think this is

```
float d = Convert.ToSingle(aTestRecord.aMecProp);
```

Comment: should be as comment.